# Tests running locally but no test generation on jenkins ‘Publish JUnit test result report’ failed: No test report files were found

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jenkins, karma-jasmine

I have been writing unit tests for my angular app and they run pretty well on jasmine . However when putting them on jenkins the build doesn't get completed and I have no report generated, I get the following error .

```
[32m28 07 2019 12:52:27.841:INFO [karma]: [39mKarma v1.7.1 server started at http://0.0.0.0:9876/
[32m28 07 2019 12:52:27.844:INFO [launcher]: [39mLaunching browser ChromeHeadless with unlimited concurrency
[32m28 07 2019 12:52:27.875:INFO [launcher]: [39mStarting browser ChromeHeadless
[31m28 07 2019 12:52:46.448:ERROR [karma]: [39m{ inspect: [Function: inspect] }
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Recording test results
ERROR: Step ‘Publish JUnit test result report’ failed: No test report files were found. Configuration error?
Finished: FAILURE
```

What I tried to do is making two separate jenkins projects . In each one I put a different test file ( in total they're two tests files) .
One of the projects run pretty well but the second one sends back the mentionned Error , I get the same error when putting both test files in the same jenkins project .

This is the project (website folder)
`https://github.com/testing-angular-applications/testing-angular-applications.git`
The tests are the two .spec files inside chapter03 (inside the same git)

At least I should get the report file but the build didn't go to that point ( no report has been generated)

Comment: Just wondering about the error message *JUnit test result report failed*: is the build step just named wrongly or is it really looking for JUnit tests? In that case it would not be surprising if it found none, since you wrote jasmine tests and not junit tests?

Comment: the build generate a XML report file and thanks to Junit plugin , the report gets generated out of that XML file

Comment: Well I can't really see how a JUnit plugin works together with your jasmine tests. JUnit is a testing environment for java? Maybe you need to explain a bit more what that build step exactly does.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved !

I had to downgrade to Jasmine core 2.4.1 .